# How can I set a stack panel's border color programmatically in C++ in WinUI3?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winui

I am working on a project using WinUI 3 in C++, and I want to change the border color of a XAML control(e.g. stackpanel) according to some condition. I have tried search it online, but most of answers are in c#, and some in C++ I have tried but got no luck.

For example: ("StackPanel" is defined in the xaml )

```
StackPanel().BorderBrush(SolidColorBrush(ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255)));
```

Then the error would come up:

> no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list
> argument types are: (winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush)
> object type is: winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::StackPanel

And another one I tried in .cpp file:

```
StackPanel().BorderBrushProperty(SolidColorBrush(Colors::Black()));
```

the error is:

> too many arguments in function call.

Why are these errors happening?

Could anyone help me on this? Or any suggestions?
Sample code would be great!

PS : I am still very new to WinUI 3 especially in C++ (there are not so much study material for C++)

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I would expect the c++ to line up mostly with the C#. But what ultimately matters is what the documentation says. What does the documentation say about stackpanel? Does it have a function called BorderBrush that takes an argument of the type you are passing? The error message says it doesn’t.

Comment: are you using the C++/WinRT templates? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-basic-windows-10-app-in-cppwinrt

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Taekahn, I have checked on Microsoft documentation, stackpanel do have BorderBrush function, but there is no more detail information on it. Do you have some information on this ? or any idea on how you would achieve the required function(change stackpanel border color)? Thanks again.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel.borderbrush?view=winrt-22000, it looks like it should be either something like (what you already tried) `StackPanel().BorderBrushProperty(SolidColorBrush(Colors::Black()));` if you're using C++/WinRT or something more like  `StackPanel.BorderBrush = SolidColorBrush(Colors::Black());` if you're using C++/CX. Since you've already tried the first, i'm guessing its the second. I don't actually have any of this stuff installed on my computer so i can't validate if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing the actual error (as best as i can replicate what you're doing) is

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'void Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::StackPanel::BorderBrush::set(Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Brush ^)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush' to 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Brush ^'  App1    c:\repos\App1\MainPage.xaml.cpp 29
```

If you create your brush like this `auto brush = ref new SolidColorBrush(...);`
And pass it to the stackpanel like this `stackpanel->BorderBrush = brush;`
Your error should go away.

Obviously how you are getting your stack panel might be different from how i did, but the point is you should be able to just set it to the value as long as you have the value in the correct form a `ref new` object in this case, it would seem.

Comment: Thanks, Taekahn, I used your code, and when I use "auto", there is an error: " cannot deduce 'auto' type", and there is this error: " no instance of constructor matches the argument list     argument types are: (winrt::Windows::UI::Color ()) ", do you know why ?

Comment: I hope you didn't you copy it exactly? `...` was meant to be a placeholder value for whatever color you want.

Comment: Hahaha, of course not, I use the color I want in the code, but the error still popup....do you have any idea?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error message you say you are now getting, but if your project is similar to mine, try removing the `()` from your example. i.e. `ref new SolidColorBrush(Windows::UI::Colors::Black)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Taekahn. Finally, I got it working using this: StackPanel().Background(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush(winrt::Windows::UI::Colors::Red()))